# Get length of subset pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an easy way to calculate the number of entries per subset in a `DataFrame`? The rows are grouped by some variable (could be month/id for example). Thanks!

**edit**

For example, if I have the following dataset

```
[['one', 2, 3],
 ['one', 3, 4],
 ['two', 4, 6]]
```

Can I calculate the length of each subset as determined by the first column? Such that the new `DataFrame` would be

```
[['one', 2, 3, 2], 
 ['one', 3, 4, 2],
 ['two', 4, 6, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `groupby` by the first column and then calculate the length of each group (using your example data, but with column names):

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame([['one', 2, 3],
   ...:  ['one', 3, 4],
   ...:  ['two', 4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

In [10]: df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: len(x))
Out[10]:
0    2
1    2
2    1
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Adding it to the dataframe:

```
In [17]: df['len'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: len(x))

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
     A  B  C  len
0  one  2  3    2
1  one  3  4    2
2  two  4  6    1
```